# Xamarin forms working in offline mode with sqllite

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need a nuget package or some good practice how to do a whole-app offline mode working? Im having login, xf maps, CRUD operations etc.
I found some guidence but it is regarding xf offline mode with azure but I really need is logging everything in my db.

Logic: after each api call (while I have internet), drop all tables, create new ones, and insert fresh data. (with delete wont work, because, those unique ids are reserved already)
when I dont have internet, read from db "old" data

Answer (score 1):

Using this you can store your data in Local storage and retrieve from that.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/store-local-data-with-sqlite/4-exercise-store-data-locally-with-sqlite

Answer (score 0):

[There is SQLite package for xamarin, in fact more than one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/get-started/quickstarts/database?pivots=windows)

Comment: That wasnt my question. I have already implemented sqllite-net extension, I need just a good example of relational model for example, if I have Favorites List page and there is a button for each item in the list favorite/unfavorite item. If Im working in offline mode, how that changes would I store it? through agregation table maybe?